# what if kernel version is different from module build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Suppose I build a module in kernel 2.6.32-431, but I load it successfully in kernel 2.6.32-432. Can this module work properly? Or is it harm to system?

Answer (score 3):

The version of your kernel is `2.6.32`.

The number you see after the dash (`-432`) is an iteration of patchsets applied by your distribution's developers. Most of those changes likely are security patches.

Moreover, 2.6.32 kernel is an LTS release, which normally doesn't accept anything, but security updates and fixes for severe issues.

So, you should not worry that module compiled with `2.6.32-431` kernel sources won't work on `2.6.32-432` kernel.

What you should really worry about is that `2.6.32` kernel is not supported since `February 2016`.

Comment: Don't bother of kernel version number. The problem is after kernel modified and compiled, the `System.map` changed. but module building needs `System.map`. What I worried about is that after kernel symbol's address changed, does it influence module?

Answer (score 2):

With such a little difference between kernel versions (`2.6.32-431` vs `2.6.32-432`) and by passing checksum check (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057098/how-is-module-version-checksum-evaluted/34061894#34061894) about checksum in Linux kernel modules), your module will **very likely** operate **correctly**.

Of course, no one can be sure about correctness.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your changes complied successfully under the module build in your new kernel version, it should not be a problem. It should work normally 99%.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk yes. Could you correct me if anything wrong?

Comment: he does NOT recompile module!